# Accessing outer loop variable from inside loop in Java

Tags: java, loops

My list consist of list character definition like `List<Character> listCharacter = new ArrayList<Character>();`

Character class:

```
private List<Result> results;
```

Result Class :

```
 private int id;

 private String name;
```

I am trying to iterate over listCharacter like

```
listCharacter.forEach((characters) -> {

            characters.getResults().forEach((result) -> {

                if (result.getId() == id) {
                    return result;
                }

            });
        });
```

But when am trying this i got **foreach not applicable the type Iterable is not applicable for the arguments (( result) -> {})** error . I know chain loop not possible with foreach loop.

Also i know we can use consumers like duplicate question solutions.But then  i can't reach outer loop variable inside inner loop.The Consumer classes just using it and disposing it.Therefore I don't wanna use that.

How can i do this i mean reaching outer loop variable inside inner loop without dealing with this such errors?

TLDR: I have 2 list objects. I am iterating over outer one(listCharacter) that who has inner one list object(result) which has id and name.If the id matched the method would return.That's all.

Comment: `forEach` doesn't return. I think you want to `map` possibly you want to `flatMap`.

Comment: I would definitely avoid calling a custom class `Character` as that already exists in the Java API. consider changing it to something more meaningful. currently `private Result results;` is not iterable . is that suppose to be a `List<Result> results` instead within `Character` class?.

Comment: I am sorry yes results type List<Result> i updated my question

Comment: Is character `id` unique across all characters? (If so, there is a much simpler approach!)

Comment: Yes they all are unique . Could you share with me your idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would firstly suggest that you avoid calling a custom class `Character` as that's already in use by the Java API. you don't have to but it would avoid confusion here and there. Consider remaining to something more meaningful and reflecting of what the class does.

Also note that you cannot return a result from `forEach`.

You can accomplish your intended result as follows:

```
source.stream()
      .map(Character::getResults)
      .flatMap(Collection::stream)
      .filter(s -> s.getId() == id)
      .findFirst().orElse(null);
```

Comment: Thank you very much.For learning why we mapped this result list ? Also with flatmap i know flatmap for having filter, sum, distinct operations. But could'nt we do that without flatmap in this case?

Answer (score 0):

"results" is not a list or any other iterator, it's just a single object of type "Result". Thus, you can not iterate over it at all. Make sure getResults() actually returns a list, rather than a single object, and then you can iterate over it.

(Also note that forEach() is not actually a loop. It's a function call with a lambda function as a parameter. And as mentioned before, you can not use forEach() to collect some kind of result from the lambda function, you'll have to use map() for that.)